# Unable to post to my database mySQLWorkBench using express.js node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, postman, mysql-workbench

I am struggling to wrap my head around all this backend stuff. I basically have set up an amazon mySQL server with RDS and using mySQLWorkBench I have connected my express.js with the following file:

```
let mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "",
    user: "admin",
    password: "",
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    connection.query('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS main;');
    connection.query('USE main;');
    connection.query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cars(id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, manufacturer varchar(100), model varchar(100), price int, PRIMARY KEY(id));', function(error, result, fields) {
        console.log(result);
    });
    connection.end();

});

module.exports = connection;
```

I already have my table set up in mySQLWorkbench, and and the connection is fine if I user the following in my server file:

```
connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Database connection failed: ' + err.stack);
      return;
    }
  
    console.log('Connected to database.');
  });
  
  connection.end();
```

However in my Index.js, I am trying to create a post endpoint (im still very new to this and not sure where I should start etc, but I was following this tutorial: https://stackabuse.com/using-aws-rds-with-node-js-and-express-js/ ).

index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000; 

const connection = require("./server");


app.listen(port, () => console.log("listening on port 3000") + port )

const dummyData = [
    
        {manufacturer: "volvo", model: "1st", price: 300},
        {manufacturer: "fiat", model: "500", price: 500},
]; 





app.post('/cars', (req, res) => {
    if (req.query.manufacturer && req.query.model && req.query.price) {
        console.log('Request received');

        connection.connect(function(err) {
            connection.query(`INSERT INTO main.cars (manufacturer, model, price) VALUES ('${req.query.manufacturer}', '${req.query.model}', '${req.query.price}')`, function(err, result, fields) {
                if (err) res.send(err);
                if (result) res.send({manufacturer: req.query.manufacturer, model: req.query.model, price: req.query.price});
                if (fields) console.log(fields);
                console.log(result)
            });
        });
    } else {
        console.log('Missing a parameter');
    }
});
```

I am really not sure if I am doing this correctly, but when I run the file and host it, it's fine, then when I try use postman to do a post request with the following fields:

```
localhost:3000/cars?manufacturer=test&model=testmodel&price=2000
```

I get the following error:

```
{
    "code": "PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_QUIT",
    "fatal": false
}
```

My goal is here, is to have a few simple endpoints for my datastore, which is to post, retrieve and update. Any help for clarification or guides would be extremely appreicated. Thanks!

Comment: your code is open to sql injection

Comment: How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'your password';
```